# NServiceBus with Azure Service Bus (Basic mode)

Tags: nservicebus, azureservicebus

sorry if now I can't provide all the details, but I'm trying to use NServiceBus on Azure Service Bus using the Basic configuration. NServiceBus fails on start because it tries to create a Topic and a Queue, and Basic mode of Azure Service Bus doesn't suport Topics. Any help or workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're talking about Basic Tier (pay).

Not with the current version of the ASB transport. Current version of transport only has one topology [`QueueAndTopicByEndpointTopology`](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AzureServiceBus/blob/master/src/Transport/Topology/QueueAndTopicByEndpoint/QueueAndTopicByEndpointTopology.cs#L14) which is creating topics by default. You have two options: switch to Paid Tier or implement an alternative topology and use that (not a trivial task). Next version of transport will support more topologies and allow better mechanism to plug custom implementations.

But have you considered the following: without Topics you cannot have pub/sub. This would be a severe limitation when using bus architecture.

Comment: Hi, Sean. Yes I'm talking about the basic tier (less expensive). I think that the part "you need to pay to use this" is  a joke. I'm aware of the limitations but it's like the Azure Queue Storage, no? It can be sort of implemented. I think this sort of things needs to be remarked on the documentation.

Comment: When a transport is created, it's created for production purposes. If you are going to learn, then you can use MSMQ locally or ASQ with emulator to cut your learning costs. ASB is a hosted service, so saying that it should be completely free is not for me to decide.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this but a Basic tier can be a valid choice for a production product. I didn't say anything about the service should be free or not, I just wanted to know why NServiceBus cannot be used with the Basic tier of Azure Service Bus and, if I could, how can be done. And for me, that limitation is a bad thing and should be expressed in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

As Sean outlined, basic tier is currently not possible out of the box. But I'm curious to know why prefer Basic tier over Storage Queues?

Comment: There is no real "why". I wanted to try how it works and how to use nservicebus with it. But, well, now I know that I can't work with this option. It's a little disappointing, but c'est la vie.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It's on our backlog though, among many other things, so this feedback is important for prioritisation purposes. If you just want to learn more about nservicebus, standard will do just fine, there is no need to be worried about the cost of azure servicebus at fairly low scales.

Comment: My thoughts are that, at least, the docs need to make clear this "limitation". I don't know if this "basic" tier is relatively new. But if it exists then there are good reasons to use it, doesn' it?